# Reliably capture the output of an external command

Tags: go

I need to call lots of short-lived (and occasionally some long-lived) external processes in rapid succession and process both `stdout` and `stderr` in realtime. I've found numerous solutions for this using `StdoutPipe` and `StderrPipe` with a `bufio.Scanner` for each, packaged into goroutines. This works most of the time, but it swallows the external command's output occasionally, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a minimal example displaying that behaviour on MacOS X (Mojave) and on Linux:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 50000; i++ {
        log.Println("Loop")

        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        cmd := exec.Command("echo", "1")
        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        cmd.Start()

        stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        stdoutScanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
                line := stdoutScanner.Text()
                log.Printf("[stdout] %s\n", line)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()

        cmd.Wait()
        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

I've left out the `stderr` handling for this. When running this, I get only about 49,900 `[stdout] 1` lines (the actual number varies with each run), though there should be 50,000. I'm seeing 50,000 `loop` lines, so it doesn't seem to die prematurely. This smells like a race condition somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

It works just fine if I don't put the scanning loop in a goroutine, but then I lose the ability to simultaneously read `stderr`, which I need.

I've tried running this with `-race`, Go reports no data races.

I'm out of ideas, what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not checking for errors in several places.

In some, this is not actually causing problems, but it's still a good idea to check:

```
cmd.Start()
```

may return an error, in which case the command was never run.  (This is not the actual problem.)

When `stdoutScanner.Scan()` returns false, `stdoutScanner.Err()` may show an error.  If you start checking this, you'll find some errors:

```
2020/02/19 15:38:17 [stdout err] read |0: file already closed
```

This isn't the actual problem, but—aha—this matches the symptoms you see: not all of the output got seen.  Now, why would reading `stdout` claim that the file is closed?  Well, where did `stdout` come from?  It's from here:

```
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
```

Take a look at the [source code for this function](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=17670:17719#L603), which ends with these lines:

```
c.closeAfterStart = append(c.closeAfterStart, pw)
c.closeAfterWait = append(c.closeAfterWait, pr)
return pr, nil
```

(and `pr` is the pipe-read return value).  Hmm: what could `closeAfterWait` mean?

Now, here are your last two lines in your loop:

```
cmd.Wait()
wg.Wait()
```

That is, first we wait for `cmd` to finish.  (When `cmd` finishes, what gets closed?)  Then we wait for the goroutine that's reading `cmd`'s stdout to finish.  (Hm, what could still be reading from the `pr` pipe?)

The fix is now obvious: swap the `wg.Wait()`, which waits for the consumer of the stdout pipe to finish reading it, with the `cmd.Wait()`, which waits for `echo ...` to exit and then closes the read end of the pipe.  If you close while the readers are still reading, they may never read what you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very insightful.